# Getting error in expect for loop

Tags: expect

**Expect Script "testscript2":**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set hostlist [open ./host_list]
set ipaddrs [read $hostlist]

foreach line [split $ipaddrs \n] {

        spawn scp id_dsa.pub root@$line:~/.ssh
        set pass "abc123"
        expect {
        "yes/no" {send "yes\r"}
        password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
                  }
}
```

The above works except there are these annoying errors which really have no effect on the outcome of the file transfer:

```
./testscript2
spawn scp id_dsa.pub root@lsvm-nagios1:~/.ssh
id_dsa.pub 100% 20 0.0KB/s 00:00
spawn scp id_dsa.pub root@:~/.ssh
ssh: : Name or service not known
lost connection
```

As you can see above the transfer occurs but the for loop iterates one extra time after there are no more server names in host_list. I think what is happening is that the last time the for loop iterates it sees that exp_continue statement and since there are no more server names in host_list it throws that error. Hence the "root@:~".

Answer (score 2):

If the host_list file ends with a newline character, the [split] will give an extra element for the empty last line.  To skip this, try adding the following line before the spawn command:

`if {$line == ""} continue`

Comment: Wow awesome let me give it a try :)

Comment: Brian, if this answer solves your problem you should mark it as "Accepted".